# Getting incompatible block pointer types sending void *(^)

Tags: iphone, ios5, objective-c-blocks

```
[AsyncRequest performGetRequestWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/api/streams/%d", @"server.herokuapp.com", userId]
                     completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
    // Create new SBJSON parser object
    NSError *e;
    NSArray *jsonArray =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    NSLog(@"parse result to JSON object with jsonArray: %@ and error: %@", jsonArray, e.description);

    if ([jsonArray valueForKey:@"error"]) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"getStreams size of the return array: %d", [jsonArray count]);
    NSMutableArray* data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    if (jsonArray) {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[jsonArray count]];
        for (NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"item: %@", item);
            [data addObject:[[Stream alloc] initWithJSONObject:item]];
        }
    }

    onComplete(data, error);

}];
```

I am getting weird error on this code.  It shows the error message "Getting incompatible block pointer types sending void *(^)(NSDictionary *_strong, NSError *_strong) to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSDictionary *_strong, NSError *_strong)'

Here is the function signature:

```
+(void)performGetRequestWithUrl:(NSString *)requestUrl completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error))completionBlock
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

change "return nil" to "return"

Comment: @flashsnake the error message is saying that you are are passing a block that returns `void *` to a parameter that expects a block returning `void`. In C and Objective-C, `void *` is the type for an arbitrary pointer; `nil` is in fact defined to be `void *(0)` so when you type `return nil` the complier infers your return type to be `void *`. Whereas if you having nothing after your `return` statement, or no `return`, it infers a return type of `void`, as expected by the parameter.